# Discover source of ACPI interrupts

Tags: linux, redhat, acpi

I have a set of linux boxes, running RHEL 5. All have the same set of packages installed, and the same hardware/BIOS/DRAC versions.I have ~3k ACPI interrupts a second on one CPU, on some, but not all machines. [This](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-firmware-acpi) indicates I can find what's causing the ACPI interrupts (or at least the interrupt types) by poking around /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/, but I don't seem to have a /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/. Any idea how else I could find the cause of the interrupts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is that you cannot with the default RHEL kernel, as ACPI debugging is turned off at compile time.